# How can I fix the following code to enumerate words of length $k$ in an alphabet?

Tags: python

In Python 3, I am writing code to make a list of words of length k, where k is a positive integer, in some given alphabet. The alphabet should be a list (for example, [a,b,c,d]).

Here is the code:

```
def list_len_k_words(alphabet, k):
list = []
if k == 1:
    return alphabet
if k >= 2:
    for i in alphabet:
        for j in list_len_k_words(alphabet,k-1):
            list = list.append(i+j)
    return list
```

This throws the error "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'". I partially understand what is happening: if I print the values of i+j that the program generates, the last value is always None. This has something to do with the return statement of my code, but I do not see how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem in your code is that you assigned the output of `list.append` to list. `append` modifies your list in place, and returns nothing (in fact, it returns `None`, as all functions that don't have an explicit return value). On the next loop, your list was `None`, so trying to append to it failed.

Note that I renamed your list to 'words', as `list` is the name of a Python builtin function.

```
def list_len_k_words(alphabet, k):
    words = []
    if k == 1:
        return alphabet
    if k >= 2:
        for i in alphabet:
            for j in list_len_k_words(alphabet,k-1):
                words.append(i+j)
        return words

list_len_k_words('abc', 2)
# ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bb', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'cc']
```

You could also have used the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module to obtain the same result:

```
from itertools import permutations

def list_len_k_words(alphabet, k):
    return [''.join(perm) for perm in permutations(alphabet, k)]
```